# convert string into variable name

Tags: php, variables

I am working on a function that takes a string as an argument, which I need to use to get the value of a variable of the same name.

For example

If the string `$foo = "$_POST['email']";` is passed I need to retrieve the value of `$_POST['email']` and store it as `$example`, so that `$_POST['email'] == $example` would return true. There is no feasable way of passing the value directly to function (the variable has to be dynamic to make the function worthwhile).

I did think of using variable variables but they don't work with super globals which will be the primary source of the values I need.

Basically is there a way to get the value of a variable (usually in a superglobal array) with the needed variable as a string?

Let me know if more detail is needed.

Thanks

Comment: To address secuity concerns, I am using a mysql table to provide a value set by admin, which itself will be restricted to a small number of possible variables and checked before going in the database. On the front end, everything is checked before this function is called and if it doesn't make sense with verified data, the function stops. To my mind that is fairly secure, but critism is welcome.

Comment: Also, why didn't I think of array keys?

Comment: "...which I need to use to get the value of a variable of the same name.". Another mind ruined by PHP. **Please. Stop. Think. Don't do that.** Think about what is *really* desired and then use an appropriate ADT. Problem averted.

Comment: My last comment may have been a tad harsh: I do not understand the actual use-case from the post. If this was laid out better, others could provide alternative answers using good programming techniques.

Answer (score 4):

Variable variables would be the answer, but if you're after fetching values from `$_POST` array, why not pass just a key to a function?

**Note:** ths function is provided just for example, my actual recommendation is below.

```
function fetchFromPost($key) {
  if(isset($_POST[$key]) {
    return $_POST[$key];
  } else {
    return null; //or do whatever you want to do in case key is not found
  }
}
```

In fact [filter_input()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.filter-input.php), which allows you to chose an input array, a key and a sanitaion filter to be used, is already there for you

Comment: +1 You could change `$_POST` to `$_REQUEST` so that you have `post`, `get` and `cookie` all at once.

Comment: @jeroen - although using $_REQUEST means you don't know where the values came from, which leaves you open to potential abuse

Comment: They all come from user, so none of them can be trusted anyway.

Comment: @Mark Baker That´s true, but the whole idea of returning a variable like that - without taking into account what it can and can´t be - already seems like a very bad idea that you should never use in a non-trusted environment. Strike that, I would never use it at all.

Comment: Nice solution, but no answer to the question. It can just read POST variables and not just any variable.

Comment: @GolezTrol: From the question: `super globals [...] will be the primary source of the values I need`. `filter_input` should be enough for that. I might also note that your solution in it's current form is also limited to super globals only.

Comment: Superglobals, yes, but not limited to _POST. I do not agree with the method of having to evaluate a string containing `$_POST['var']` and I would suggest the OP to find another solution, but if that's not possible, you'll need eval of a similar solution or go parse the string yourself. filter_input also needs a source (post) and a key, so it's essentially a more flexible solution than fetchFromPost.

Comment: Once again, my actual recomendation is to use `filter_input()`. The function in my answer can be modified to work with all super globals, but is there pretty much for example's sake.

Answer (score 2):

It is possible, although I **seriously** doubt you should use this. **It allows for PHP injection and makes your source code *very vulnerable*** if you don't know where the string came from:

```
<?
function eval_expression($expression)
{
    eval("\$temp = $expression;");
    return $temp;
}

// Usage:
echo eval_expression("\$_GET['plop']");
```

Comment: -1 Just for the sake of using `eval`, even with the non-stressed disclaimer (Not that this approach may not work, rather that **this approach *should not* be promoted.**)

Comment: Yeah, maybe I should have stressed it more. I did in another reply that I deleted because the solution I gave there was wrong. Still feels a bit wrong to downvote what seems to be the only working solution to the literal question, unless you know a different and better one. For now, please accept this answer for what it is. A glimpse on the dark side, for education purposes only. ;-)

Comment: Added some bold and italic. ;-)